# How to include statusbar space in UITableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, statusbar

I am using a UITableviewcontroller, and set an image for the background of the tableView.

How can I include the top white space (Stausbar)in to the view with out hide statusbar.

[image]

Comment: Did you try removing its background color? `tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`

Comment: I dont want to remove the big color. I Want to extend the screen up to top .

Comment: @VineeshTP Are you was see my answer is it working ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by changing the top constraints from `SafeArea.top to superview.top`

Answer (score -1):

You must set contentInset top StatusBar Height.

```
let statusBarHeight:CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -statusBarHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

If you using StoryBoard Set top value : -20 
[image: Set top -20]